# Why my Kivy 1.9 desktop app when run from source able to display in high res mode, but not when it is run after packaged by PyInstaller?

Tags: python, kivy

As you know, the latest stable release of Kivy (1.9) already support Retina Display. When I run my desktop app from the source, I can clearly see that it use a high res display (not blurred). But when I package the app using PyInstaller, it revert itself to low-res display, making it look like it is run from Kivy 1.8 (haven't support Retina Display).

Any ideas what cause this? I am currently working on it, but be glad if someone out there know how to solve this issue

Comment: You may have more luck with this one on the kivy irc or mailing list, there are more eyes there for such problems.

Comment: Great. Just about to do that. I will report the solution back here. Thanks